# Extract line with regexp php

Tags: php, regex, numbers, extract

http://www.goldfixing.com/vars/goldfixing.vars
I have this file, and there is
this line

&pmeuro=983.327 &

How can I extract only number from that file?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$string = '&pmeuro=983.327 &';

preg_match('/([0-9\.]+)/', $string, $matches);
```

`$matches` will return an array of values matching the RegEx pattern. In this case 983.327.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match("/pmeuro=(.+)&/", "pmeuro=983.327&", $matches);

echo $matches[1] ;
```